# The Monodromy Representation of a Riemann Riemann Surface with a Singular Projective Structure

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, riemann-surfaces, complex-manifolds, monodromy

Let $R$ be a Riemann Surface with a Regular Projective Structure $\nu$.

Questions:

1. What is the **Monodromy Representation** $\mu: \pi_1(R) \longrightarrow PSL(2,\mathbb{C})$, how to define it?
2. If the projective structure $\nu$ is **Singular** how to define the monodromy representation?

Referring to certain references is truly enough.

Comment: I suggest you read Goldman's book on geometric structures that you can find [here](http://www2.math.umd.edu/~wmg/gstom.pdf). In the case of a singular projective structures, you simply remove the singular set and consider the monodromy  (aka holonomy) of the regular projective structure on the  remaining surface.

Comment: @MoisheKohan than you so much, which page exactly?

Comment: Section 5.2 of the book.

Comment: @MoisheKohan thank you so much